# Raven's progressive matrices test

Tags: pattern

I found this question while doing an official Mensa practice test. 
**Please fill in the bottom right blank window with one of the 6 possible answers depicted below the horizontal line.**[image]

Comment: are there any rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is

> the right one in the top row.

Because:

> there are three basic shapes on the 9 images: the circle (top row middle), the triangle (second row middle), and the U-shaped thingy (second row right).
>  They all appear in three forms:
>
>  1. the basic variation
>
>  2. a version in which the basic shapes right and left sides are swapped
>    - two facing half circles
>    - the rotated K
>    - and the upside-down T
>
>  3. and a variation in which their right half is rotated 180 degrees
>    - the CC-looking stuff
>    - the bottom middle one
>    - and... the one that is missing, so it must be a half U followed by the otherhalf of the half U, rotated upside down

Comment: One hypothetical problem would be that the first row, first square could be the "base" design for the U-shaped thingy, and then the U itself would be the second version, then the answer would be a 180° rotation of your selected answer...but that's not a choice.

Comment: not convinced, seems the `((` sshould be `))` why prefer the triangle over the "dead" `K`

Comment: the CC is fine, I think, please check it once more. My idea does not work with the the dead K chosen as a basic shape, but works with the triangle, that's why I chose that one. I've been designing Raven-like puzzles for standardized IQ test questions, and I'm aware of the rules behind their solution. This one seems like a question with the idea of 'distribution of 3 values', but the placement of the tiles is a little bit strange indeed. I can accept if you think my idea is a stretch. [to be continued]

Comment: [cont.] Being part of an official Mensa test suggests that this is a high quality matrix question, which should 100 percently fit to the mentioned rules. When you were filling the test, was this the only 'strange' question? Are you convinced this is a standard, official question from Raven? How was the overall quality of the test?

Comment: @elias this question is part of a practice test which can be found on the official mensa - Greece website.

Comment: For me that's a little bit weird, because I can't yet see it as a question perfectly meeting the design criteria of the Raven matrices. But also I can totally understand, if a publicly available, free test has some imperfect questions. That being said, it is possible there is a neater solution than mine, and then all this reasoning does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

An answer that's at least plausible is

> [image]

There are three groups of shapes, the circle thingies, the triangle thingies, and the squarish thingies.

To go from the first-row shape to the second-row shape, you

> halve the picture vertically, then swap the halves.

To go from the first-row shape to the third-row shape, you

> halve the picture vertically, flip the left half vertically, the right half horizontally, then flip the whole thing horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is:

> [[image]

## Why

> A = [image: Shape1]
>  B = [image: Shape2]
>  If you rotate B, the line goes up.
>  If you rotate A, the line goes bottom.
>  Remove the triangle from A and add line in A in B.
>  It becomes the solution.

Comment: Please explain why you think this is the answer.

Comment: I did it, Can anyone hide my box?

Comment: I don't understand why you think A and B are related.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a clear and/or simple answer, but I believe that it is

> option 3, since the right second horizontal row contains part of a  shape. If you cut the right half and turn it 180 degrees, and keep the other half preserved, you will get option 3.

Comment: Weight never mind I have a better explanation. This works for every shape between the 2nd and 3 rd row. Swap the sides, horizontally flip the right side and vertically flip the left side. The answer is solution 3.

Comment: only works given that "horizontally flip" is ambiguous is it `b` to `d` or `b` to `p` you seem to be using the term both ways.